# Rust Spelling corrector

Tags: algorithm, rust

It's been about a day since I've started writing some Rust, and I'm looking for some code review on a simple spell checker I've written up

```
use generator::{Gn, Generator, Scope, done};
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::ops::Add;

use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;


#[derive(Debug)]
struct EditWord {
    word: String,
    editDistance: usize,
}

impl EditWord {
    fn new(w: String, editDistance: usize) -> EditWord {
        return EditWord { word: w, editDistance };
    }
}


static ASCII_LOWER: [char; 26] = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
    'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
    'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y',
    'z',
];


type Stream<'s, T> = Generator<'s, (), T>;


#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct WordDataSet {
    counter: HashMap<String, usize>
}



impl<'a> From<Vec<&'a str>> for WordDataSet {
    fn from(vec: Vec<&'a str>) -> Self {
        let mut counter = HashMap::new();
        for w in vec {
            *counter.entry(w.to_string()).or_default() += 1;
        }
        return WordDataSet { counter };
    }
}

impl WordDataSet {
    pub fn prob(&self, word: &str) -> f64 {
        if !self.counter.contains_key(word) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        return *self.counter.get(word).unwrap() as f64 / self.counter.values().sum::<usize>() as f64;
    }

    fn exists(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
        return self.counter.contains_key(word);
    }
}


fn splits(w: &str) -> Vec<(&str, &str)> {
    (0..=w.len()).map(|i| w.split_at(i)).collect()
}


pub struct SimpleCorrector {
    data_set: WordDataSet
}


impl SimpleCorrector {
    pub fn correct(&self, word: &str) -> Option<String> {
        if self.data_set.exists(word) {
            return Some(word.to_string());
        }

        edits(1, word)
            .filter(|e| self.data_set.exists(&e.word))
            .map(|e| ((1 / e.editDistance) as f64 * self.data_set.prob(&e.word), e.word))
            .max_by(|(p1, w1), (p2, w2)| p1.partial_cmp(p2).expect("Tried to compare NAN"))
            .map(|(p, w)| w)
    }
}


fn edit1(w: &str) -> Stream<String> {
    let pairs = splits(w);
    let g = Gn::new_scoped(move |mut s| {
        //deletes
        for (a, b) in pairs.iter() {
            let delete = format!("{}{}", a, b.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
            s.yield_(delete);
        }

        for (a, b) in pairs.iter() {
            for c in ASCII_LOWER.iter() {

                //replace
                let replace = format!("{}{}{}", a, c, b.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
                s.yield_(replace);

                //insert
                let insert = format!("{}{}{}", a, c, b);
                s.yield_(insert);
            }
        }

        done!();
    });
    return g;
}

fn edits(n: usize, word: &str) -> Stream<EditWord> {
    let g = Gn::new_scoped(move |mut s| {
        let mut v = vec![word.to_string()];
        let mut seen = HashSet::new();
        seen.insert(word.to_string());
        for i in 0..n {
            let mut next_list = vec![];
            for word in v {
                for w in edit1(&word) {
                    if !seen.contains(&w) {
                        next_list.push(w.to_string());
                        seen.insert(w.to_string());
                        let editWord = EditWord::new(w.to_string(), i + 1);
                        s.yield_(editWord);
                    }
                }
            }
            v = next_list;
        }
        done!();
    });
    return g;
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_word_prob() {
        let data_set = WordDataSet::from(vec!["A", "B"]);
        assert_eq!(data_set.prob("B"), 0.5)
    }


    #[test]
    fn test_word_split() {
        let word = "abc";
        let word_splits = splits(word);
        assert_eq!(word_splits, vec![("", "abc"),
                                     ("a", "bc"),
                                     ("ab", "c"),
                                     ("abc", "")])
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_corrector_on_valid_word() {
        let word = "ab";
        let word_list = vec!["ab", "cd"];
        let word_dataset = WordDataSet::from(word_list);
        let s = SimpleCorrector { data_set: word_dataset };
        let res = s.correct("ab");
        dbg!(res);
    }


    #[test]
    fn test_corrector_on_invalid_word() {
        let test_word = "aa";
        let word_list = vec!["ab", "cd"];
        let word_dataset = WordDataSet::from(word_list);
        let s = SimpleCorrector { data_set: word_dataset };
        let res = s.correct(test_word);
        assert_eq!(res.unwrap(), "ab");
    }
}
```

Deps:

```
[dependencies]
generator = "0.6.19"
```

I've got to add more tests to test the logic again, but so far I think it's alright. I'm mainly looking for pointers on how I can exploit the type system better, and how to write shorter, ergonomic code.

I'm quite sure the `.to_string()` calls in the `edits` function can be reduced, but not sure how.

Comment: @Shepmaster, done, thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster, whoops that was just an extraneous artifiact from before -- removed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First thoughts

1. **Read and act on** the warnings provided by the compiler. That's one of the biggest points of a compiled language. Do not ignore the **10+** warnings. You have a ton of unused imports, unused variables, and non-idiomatic variable names.
2. Run [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt), a tool for automatically formatting Rust code to the community-accepted style.
3. Run [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy), a tool for finding common mistakes that may not be compilation errors but are unlikely to be what the programmer intended. This points out that almost all of your uses of `return` are non-idiomatic.

#### `impl EditWord`

1. Don't abbreviate the argument `w`; call it `word` and use the struct shorthand  syntax.

#### `impl<'a> From<Vec<&'a str>> for WordDataSet`

1. There's no obvious reason to require a `Vec`. This could equally be `FromIterator`.
2. The required conversion to `String` is unfortunate. [How do I use the Entry API with an expensive key that is only constructed if the Entry is Vacant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51542024/155423) talks about a future solution. Also, you could avoid allocation completely here by storing the string slices instead.

#### `impl WordDataSet`

1. Don't look up in a map twice. Instead, use `get` once and work with the `Option`.
2. Using `as` is dubious for integer <-> floating point conversions. It's better to use `TryFrom` and panic instead. See [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423) for more details.

#### `fn splits`

1. This doesn't need to return a `Vec` as you only iterate over it. You can return an iterator instead. In this case, you also need to make it `Clone` so that you can use it twice in `edit1`, but you could probably iterate just once or call `splits` twice, as it's cheap. See [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423).

#### `impl SimpleCorrector`

1. Instead of always returning a `String`, you could return a `Cow<str>`. This would avoid allocation when the word is correctly spelled.

#### `fn edit1`

1. It's more common to use `&collection` than `collection.iter()`.

#### `fn test_corrector_on_valid_word`

1. This has no assertions.

#### `fn test_corrector_on_invalid_word`

1. I avoid using `unwrap` whenever possible. It's fine in tests, but I still try.

#### General

1. From an outside API, it's not clear what benefit there is to exposing both `WordDataSet` and `SimpleCorrector`. Perhaps the API should be restricted to one.
2. I'm not excited about the `generator` crate. This may just be ignorance on my part, but I'd probably strive to use standard iterator techniques until Rust gains stable first-class support for generators

```rust
use generator::{done, Generator, Gn};
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    iter::FromIterator,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct EditWord {
    word: String,
    edit_distance: usize,
}

impl EditWord {
    fn new(word: String, edit_distance: usize) -> EditWord {
        EditWord {
            word,
            edit_distance,
        }
    }
}

static ASCII_LOWER: [char; 26] = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
    't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
];

type Stream<'s, T> = Generator<'s, (), T>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct WordDataSet {
    counter: HashMap<String, usize>,
}

impl<'a> FromIterator<&'a str> for WordDataSet {
    fn from_iter<I>(words: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>,
    {
        let mut counter = HashMap::new();
        for w in words {
            *counter.entry(w.to_string()).or_default() += 1;
        }
        WordDataSet { counter }
    }
}

impl WordDataSet {
    pub fn prob(&self, word: &str) -> f64 {
        self.counter.get(word).map_or(0.0, |&c| {
            let sum: usize = self.counter.values().sum();
            c as f64 / sum as f64
        })
    }

    fn exists(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
        self.counter.contains_key(word)
    }
}

fn splits(w: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&str, &str)> + Clone {
    (0..=w.len()).map(move |i| w.split_at(i))
}

pub struct SimpleCorrector {
    data_set: WordDataSet,
}

impl SimpleCorrector {
    pub fn correct(&self, word: &str) -> Option<String> {
        if self.data_set.exists(word) {
            return Some(word.to_string());
        }

        edits(1, word)
            .filter(|e| self.data_set.exists(&e.word))
            .map(|e| {
                (
                    (1 / e.edit_distance) as f64 * self.data_set.prob(&e.word),
                    e.word,
                )
            })
            .max_by(|(p1, _w1), (p2, _w2)| p1.partial_cmp(p2).expect("Tried to compare NAN"))
            .map(|(_p, w)| w)
    }
}

fn edit1(w: &str) -> Stream<String> {
    let pairs = splits(w);
    Gn::new_scoped(move |mut s| {
        //deletes
        for (a, b) in pairs.clone() {
            let delete = format!("{}{}", a, b.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
            s.yield_(delete);
        }

        for (a, b) in pairs {
            for c in &ASCII_LOWER {
                //replace
                let replace = format!("{}{}{}", a, c, b.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
                s.yield_(replace);

                //insert
                let insert = format!("{}{}{}", a, c, b);
                s.yield_(insert);
            }
        }

        done!();
    })
}

fn edits(n: usize, word: &str) -> Stream<EditWord> {
    Gn::new_scoped(move |mut s| {
        let mut v = vec![word.to_string()];
        let mut seen = HashSet::new();
        seen.insert(word.to_string());
        for i in 0..n {
            let mut next_list = vec![];
            for word in v {
                for w in edit1(&word) {
                    if !seen.contains(&w) {
                        next_list.push(w.to_string());
                        seen.insert(w.to_string());
                        let edit_word = EditWord::new(w.to_string(), i + 1);
                        s.yield_(edit_word);
                    }
                }
            }
            v = next_list;
        }
        done!();
    })
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_word_prob() {
        let data_set = WordDataSet::from_iter(vec!["A", "B"]);
        assert_eq!(data_set.prob("B"), 0.5)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_word_split() {
        let word = "abc";
        let word_splits = splits(word).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        assert_eq!(
            word_splits,
            vec![("", "abc"), ("a", "bc"), ("ab", "c"), ("abc", "")]
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_corrector_on_valid_word() {
        let word_list = vec!["ab", "cd"];
        let data_set = WordDataSet::from_iter(word_list);
        let s = SimpleCorrector { data_set };
        let res = s.correct("ab");
        dbg!(res);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_corrector_on_invalid_word() {
        let test_word = "aa";
        let word_list = vec!["ab", "cd"];
        let data_set = WordDataSet::from_iter(word_list);
        let s = SimpleCorrector { data_set };
        let res = s.correct(test_word);
        assert_eq!(res.as_deref(), Some("ab"));
    }
}
```